# Improve performance of a dockerized OrientDB

Tags: performance, docker, orientdb

We are going to implement a recommender system to be used in a e-commerce portal. We store all the data that the system processes in a dockerized OrientDB and the type of our storage is 'plocal'.

To be effective, a recommender system has to provide an answer in the shortest time possible, so we want to obtain the best possible performance when we fetch data from the database.

We have already perform an optimization of the queries and we would like to know if there are other workarounds to improve performance in our situation.

Any suggestion? When using orientDB with Docker, there are some specific improvements that is possible to adopt? It is useful to increment the RAM of the docker container? What are the pro and cons of the other storage types with respect to plocal?

Comment: Hi, what OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: I am using OrientDB 2.2.29